# named -> rsyslogd. Записывать каждые n-строк

Tags: rsyslog

Есть сервер DNS. Есть сервер rsyslog. В журналы пишется категория "queries" - это необходимо для статистики и отслеживания аномальных запросов. Но запросов очень много и журнал разрастается на несколько ГБ. Хотелось бы как-то уменьшить объём записываемых данных.

Возможно ли либо named'у, либо rsyslog'у дать указание сохранять только каждые n-строк, отбрасывая остальные? Либо инной вариант записи лишь части сообщений (например минуту сохранять данные в журнал, 4 минуты - отбрасывать). Ни для rsyslog'а, ни для named'а в Сети подходящих опций найти не удалось, но может есть какой-то хитрый малоизвестный приём?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дублировать с помощью **rsyslog** логи на удалённое многотерабайтное хранилище (Для истории/изучения) где принимающей стороной может выступать всё тот же rsyslog, это настраивается в пару строк, а на сервере(-ах) с **named** настроить почасовую (Либо как Вам удобнее) ротацию этого лога с помощью **logrotate**. Так же можно сказать rsyslog'у отдавать логи налету а какой-то скрипт который будет с ними делать что Вам нужно, в т.ч. отбрасывать лишние строки (Но если Вас интересует лично моё мнение, это какой-то "очень не очень" вариант с отбрасыванием строк).

Comment: Спасибо! Ваша фраза про почасовую ротацию журнала очень помогла. Сбор статистики можно переделать, а для отслеживания аномалий будет достаточно хранить данные лишь за пару последних часов, а не суточные. Это значительно сократит объёмы. Решение простое, но иногда даже самые очевидные вещи можно упустить, если зациклиться на другом :)

Comment: @МАН69К всегда рад помочь!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю в Вашем случае стоит разбить задачу на несколько и решать их отдельно:

**1. Аналитика**.

Для того чтобы ее вести достаточно хранить данные только за 1 полный день
и сохранять только результат агрегации.

**2. Хранение.**

Остальные данные можно архивировать и убирать в дешевое (в вашем случае очень) внешнее хранилище типа amazon s3 после чего удалять с локального диска.

**3. Отслеживание аномальных запросов.**

Тут можно использовать данные как с локального диска так и из удаленного хранилища

P.s. Избавляться от данных в принципе не зачем

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ так же помог в формировании окончательного решения задачи. По поводу архивирования - да, сейчас со старыми журналами так и просходит. Но 6 ГБ даже после сжатия составляют значительный объём :)